# Conditionally apply an attribute (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, conditional-statements

The issue is when I try to conditionally apply a 'has-dropdown' attribute, I get the following Angular transclusion error:

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'hasDropdown', required by directive 'ngTransclude', can't be found! 
It references angular.js line 9563

. The logic I am trying to apply is:

- If the subNav array is empty, then do not display the 'has-dropdown' attribute in the element.
- If it is not empty, then add the 'has-dropdown' attribute.

Anything that I'm missing?

```
 <code>
<li ng-repeat="nav in app.mainNavItems" 

 {{app.mainNavItems.subNavs.length > 0 ? "has-dropdown" : ""}}>  
 </code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in this way. You should create a directive, which on compile stage should check if `app.mainNavItems.subNavs.length > 0` and add attribute with `$element.attr('has-dropdown')`

Something like this:

```
var myModule = angular.module(...);

myModule.directive('directiveName', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
             if($parse(tAttrs.directiveName)()) {
                 tElement.attr('has-dropdown');
             }
        }
    };
});
```

template:

```
<li ng-repeat="nav in app.mainNavItems" directive-name="app.mainNavItems.subNavs.length > 0">
```

Note: not tested, just from the top of my head..

Comment: Thanks for your time Domakas So for example, if (array.length > 0)  the Li needs to look like this     <li ng-repeat="nav in app.mainNavItems" has-dropdown>.   And if (array.length < 0)      <li ng-repeat="nav in app.mainNavItems">    Your code simply assigns true or false which is different to what I'm trying to achieve.